# How to map a jpa result to json

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, count, persistence

I have this entity

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Scanlog {
    private String docId;
    private String userName;
    private Timestamp scanDate;
    private Integer scanPlaza;
    private long conteo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DOC_ID", nullable = false, length = 12)
    public String getDocId() {
        return docId;
    }

    public void setDocId(String docId) {
        this.docId = docId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SCAN_DATE", nullable = false)
    public Timestamp getScanDate() {
        return scanDate;
    }

    public void setScanDate(Timestamp scanDate) {
        this.scanDate = scanDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SCAN_PLAZA", nullable = true)
    public Integer getScanPlaza() {
        return scanPlaza;
    }

    public void setScanPlaza(Integer scanPlaza) {
        this.scanPlaza = scanPlaza;
    }

    public Scanlog() {
    }

    public Scanlog(String docId, String userName, Timestamp scanDate, Integer scanPlaza) {
        this.docId = docId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.scanDate = scanDate;
        this.scanPlaza = scanPlaza;
    }

    public Scanlog(String userName, long conteo) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.conteo = conteo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Scanlog scanlog = (Scanlog) o;
        return Objects.equals(docId, scanlog.docId) && Objects.equals(userName, scanlog.userName) && Objects.equals(scanDate, scanlog.scanDate) && Objects.equals(scanPlaza, scanlog.scanPlaza);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(docId, userName, scanDate, scanPlaza);
    }
}
```

and I have a class called apiDAOImpl like this:

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import com.example.demo.Scanlog;
import com.example.demo.util.Conexion;

import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class apiDAOImpl implements apiDAOLocal {

    Conexion conexion = new Conexion();

    @Override
    public List<Scanlog> listScanSummary() {
        List<Scanlog> json = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            conexion.abrir();
            Query q = conexion.em.createQuery("SELECT s.userName, count(s) from Scanlog s where DATE(s.scanDate) = current_date group by s.userName");
            json = q.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conexion.cerrar();
        }
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Scanlog> listScanSummaryTest() {
        List<Scanlog> json = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            conexion.abrir();
            Query q = conexion.em.createQuery("SELECT s from Scanlog s where DATE(s.scanDate) = current_date");
            json = q.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conexion.cerrar();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

When I call the function `listScanSummaryTest` from my controller, this function is executed

```
Query q = conexion.em.createQuery("SELECT s from Scanlog s where DATE(s.scanDate) = current_date");
```

and I get something like this:

```
[
    {
        "docId": "22R110041369",
        "userName": "HLOPEZ",
        "scanDate": 1647267784991,
        "scanPlaza": 1
    },
    {
        "docId": "22R110041370",
        "userName": "HLOPEZ",
        "scanDate": 1647267785944,
        "scanPlaza": 1
    }
]
```

But when I call the function `listScanSummary` from my controller, I want this query to be executed:

```
Query q = conexion.em.createQuery("SELECT s.userName, count(s) from Scanlog s where DATE(s.scanDate) = current_date group by s.userName");
```

And I get this:

```
[
    [
        "HGLOPEZ",
        118
    ],
    [
        "HLOPEZ",
        298
    ]
]
```

and i would like to have something like this:

```
[
    {
        "userName": "HLOPEZ",
        "count": 118
    },
    {
        "userName": "HLOPEZ",
        "count": 298
    }
]
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-PFD2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

NOTE: i'm not using spring. Just javaee (1.8) and jpa

thanks for your help!!

Comment: your code is correct because you are select just two var in your query `SELECT s.userName, count(s) from Scanlog` then it will return a array of strings instead in your test function you are selecting the entire object `SELECT s from Scanlog s` then the resutl is an array of object

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment your query `SELECT s.userName, count(s) from Scanlog s` return a array of strings and in your test function you are selecting the entire object `SELECT s from Scanlog` s then the resutl is an array of object:

So if you want to return the expected result:

```
[
    {
        "userName": "HLOPEZ",
        "count": 118
    },
    {
        "userName": "HLOPEZ",
        "count": 298
    }
]
```

You have to create a model with userName and count attribut with a constructor which hold this fields.

Then in your query you can create an Object which took this fields.

For example :

```
Select new com.CustomObject(s.userName, count(s))
```